# How to select latest purchase of customer using two or more fields in group by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have two tables, from which I need to select the latest purchase of each customer from the US. The query must present the user_id and the purchased item columns:

(I left out some of the records from both tables)

**customers**

| user_ID | created_at | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A34212213 | 2021-06-03 14:31:35 | USA |
| BK76584I | 2022-01-02 14:31:35 | USA |

**purchases**

| user_ID | date_of_purchase | purchased_item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A34212213 | 2021-12-30 01:54:07 | Hamburger |
| A34212213 | 2021-12-02 17:02:59 | Chips |
| A34212213 | 2021-12-01 06:37:59 | Potatos |
| A34212213 | 2021-12-22 12:02:39 | Hamburger |
| BK76584I | 2021-12-02 08:55:30 | Ice |
| BK76584I | 2021-12-19 12:22:12 | Gummies |
| BK76584I | 2021-12-15 22:07:43 | Hotdogs |

the result would be:

| user_id | purchased_item |
| --- | --- |
| A34212213 | Hamburger |
| BK76584I | Gummies |

I tried writing this query:

`SELECT c.user_id, purchased_item, MAX(date_of_purchase) FROM customers c JOIN purchases p ON c.user_id = p.user_id WHERE country = 'USA' GROUP BY c.user_id, purchased_item;`

But it still gives me multiple records of the same user_ID, because the purchased_item is different in most records. I can't seem to figure out how to get only one record of each user_ID and their latest purchase, using two or more fields in the gorup by clause.

Thanks in advance for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT c.user_id, p.purchased_item, p.date_of_purchase,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.user_id ORDER BY p.date_of_purchase DESC) AS rn
FROM customers c
JOIN purchases p
ON c.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE country = 'USA'
)
SELECT user_id, purchased_item
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for all, so that others can understand what yu have done

Comment: I don't know why I haven't thought about using a window function with ROW_NUMBER(). This is perfect, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The subquery filters the last item each user bought.

```
SELECT c.user_id, p.purchased_item
FROM customers c
JOIN purchases p ON c.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE country = 'USA' AND date_of_purchase = 
  (SELECT MAX(date_of_purchase) FROM purchases p2 WHERE p2.user_id = c.user_id);
```

### TEST

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ffae8/2

Comment: please add an explanation

Comment: I would love to get an explanation as well. It does work, but i don't understand how do we get the latest purchase date of each user when going into the subquery. Thank! :)

Comment: the subquery runs for each row, it does not bring the whole set of user and last purchase. We can use a cte for that propose performance wise